# Express JS install

Tags: node.js, installation, express

I was trying to install expressjs.

I keep getting this error here :

```
 node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: No such module
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/output.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/log.js:21:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
```

any idea why that error is occurring. I installed npm there doesnt seem to be any problem with that.

this is the command I try to use for installing express js :

```
sudo npm install express -g
```

I tried with the guide on the expressjs [website](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) as well.
Sorry, my bad. dint install latest version of nodejs

Comment: Is this error showing up when installing anything else ?

Comment: No ,it did not come while trying to install socket io .. Don't know about the others

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have a newer version of Node.js and an older version of NPM.  It sounds like you just updated Node.js, so now you need to update NPM.

Comment: But everything works fine for me. No problems at-all. 
I use the NPM version 1.1.12 and node version 0.6.14. 

Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using an old NPM version somehow.

Do

```
node --version
npm --version
```

Also, there are two packages in Ubuntu that have similar names, `node` and `nodejs`.

> Fedora also follows a similar package naming scheme. Because of this,
>   the binary in nodejs had to be renamed to nodejs from the original
>   node. However, this isn't technically kosher: and most nodejs programs
>   (and libraries installed with npm) assume that the node binary is
>   node. If you want to get around this the easiest way is just symlink
>   the two together. If you take this route, don't install the node
>   package which handles the Amateur Packet Radio stuff.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

Alternatively, in the case of `node`, I'd suggest using `n` and not installing link. Just install `npm` (which will install node), then remove `npm`, then tell apt to clean it up. To do this, simply run

```
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n latest
sudo apt-get --purge remove npm
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

There are other binary distro managers that even work from a shell script like `nvm` but I personally prefer `n`. Think of `n` like an `apt` for just one thing: the node binary which it installs to `/usr/local/bin`.